# Visual Studio c# auto indent selection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, auto-indent

I would like to perform auto indentation on my c# code in visual studio, however the (Ctrl K,D) option reports "The key combination (Ctrl K,D) is not a command".

I try Ctrl K, Ctrl D but this also has no effect.

Even when I select Edit->Advanced->Format Selection, this has no effect.

Update :

It appears that for code such as

```
XElement element1 = new XElement("books",
    books.Select(x => new XElement("book",
       new XElement("name", x.Name),
       new XElement("price", x.Price))));
```

The format selection or format document commands have no effect, however these commands work for more 'regular' constructs.

Comment: Did you see Visual Studio 2013 keyboard shortcuts?
[The complete list](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/)

Comment: No but I have the Visual Studio 2008 shortcuts poster, which states that Ctrl K,D  performs Edit.FormatDocument and Ctrl K,F performs Edit.FormatSelection. Neither of them work for me.

Comment: The code formatter, unfortunately, isn't smart enough to deal with fluent APIs. The best you'll get is one level of indentation all the way through because it sees the initial function call spans every line.

Comment: What do you mean that it's not formatted automatically? Do you mean that it's not automatically formatted _the way you'd like it to be_? Also, is this in a .cs file?

Comment: I've made an edit to clarify. Yes this is in a .cs file.

Comment: C# doesn't have a code formatter any more.  Well, there's a partial implementation of one, but as you've discovered it's not actually useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu: Edit/Advanced has some formatting commands. You should see their associated shortcuts as well.

For me it shows:

- Ctrl + E, D - format document
- Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F - format selection

Comment: For me, your first suggestion does not work, but the second does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going into Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and from there find "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme:" at the top and select Visual C# 2005 if it's not already..

Comment: Thanks I tried this but no luck unfortunately. I selected visual studio 2005 and could see  Edit.FormatSelection and Edit.FormatDocument in the list but the shortcuts didn't work.

Comment: @user1400716 Oh sorry I didn't read correctly, even selecting it from the drop down doesn't work? No idea then unless your file isn't in an editable state or it's already in the proper format or (maybe) there's some syntax error that's preventing it from formatting

Comment: The syntax seems ok and the code compiles. I've cut and pasted from a pdf. Perhaps this is the issue.

Comment: Perhaps. I would do a test with a clean file where you make an obvious formatting 'error' like too many spaces to begin a line or something